# Gradle DSL method not found: complie()

Tags: android-studio

Error:(17, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:

The project 'WizardPagerrr_production_server' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
}
}
 allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
android {
compileSdkVersion  21
buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is telling you what's wrong:

> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

You need an `apply plugin` statement in your build file to tell Gradle how to build the module. If this module is an Android Application module that will output an APK, use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

If it's a library module that will output an AAR, use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

The deeper meaning of the error message is that in this context Gradle doesn't have a definition for the `compile` dependency directive (i.e it's not built in to Gradle). It needs the Android Gradle plugin to set that up.